# Where to add UIPinchgesture on UIImageView which scale or on UIView in which UIImageView contain?

Tags: iphone, uiimageview, uipinchgesturerecognizer

Experts!!
Please help me in this!!!!!
In my project I am programatically creating multiple UIImageviews. I want to add Pinch gesture on each ImageView.i
My code is below....

```
-(IBAction)addSymbols:(UIButton *)sender{
if (sender.tag ==1) {
CGRect frame =sender.frame;
[self.imgView setFrame:frame];
self.imgView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[imgView setImage:[sender imageForState:UIControlStateNormal]];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
[self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:imgView];}
```

Like this I am adding 5 imageViews. Now code of [self addGestureRecognizersToPiece:imgView]

```
- (void)addGestureRecognizersToPiece:(UIView *)piece{
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchGesture = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scalePiece:)];
[piece  addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture];

//In above add gesture on UIImageView directly its not working..
//if replace this line by [self.view addGestureRecognizer:pinchGesture]; it's working..
//but while pinch whole UIview scale

[pinchGesture setDelegate:self]; }
```

Another bug is UIPinchgesture is not correctly working on multiple UIImageViews individually.
So please help me.. Reply me soon..

```
- (void) scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)paramSender{ 

if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) { 
self.currentScale = paramSender.scale;
} 
else if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan && self.currentScale != 0.0f){ 

paramSender.scale = self.currentScale; }
 if (paramSender.scale != NAN && paramSender.scale != 0.0){ 
[paramSender view].transform= CGAffineTransformMakeScale(paramSender.scale, paramSender.scale); 
}
```

As you told me I added userInteractionEnabled = YES for each UIImageView. I mention in my code also

Answer (score 0):

You should enable `userInteractionEnabled` on the UIImageViews. This is disabled by default.

If you need more help, please show us your `scalePiece:`code.

Comment: - (void) scalePiece:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)paramSender{
  

     if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)

    { self.currentScale = paramSender.scale;}
    else if (paramSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan && self.currentScale != 0.0f){
    paramSender.scale = self.currentScale; }
    if (paramSender.scale != NAN && paramSender.scale != 0.0){
    [paramSender view].transform= CGAffineTransformMakeScale(paramSender.scale, paramSender.scale);
    }

As you told me I added userInteractionEnabled = YES for each UIImageView. I mention in my code also

Comment: who should read that.. put it in your post pls. And also describe your exact problem. What *doesnt* work, what behaves wrong!?

Comment: I posted my whole code above.. Now reply me if there any changes in my code

Answer (score 0):

Add the imageViews as subview of ScrollView.

Then set the scrollView zoomScale of the scrollView.
Also implement the delegate methods of scrollView especially the one below.

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

return the imageView object you want to zoom.

refer these
[UIScrollView](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html)

[UIScrollViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html)

Comment: Ohhk.. i'l try this one too.. I was thinking about replace my UIPinchgesture with UIscrollview and hanldle by its delegate..Thanx for reply..